# Uso do gentílico "Russo" no português

Tags: etimologia

Recentemente estive pensando sobre o uso de [gentílicos](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/gent%C3%ADlico) em diferentes idiomas. Me chamou atenção que o gentílico [russo](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/russo) parece ter seu significado associado a ações extremas ou arriscadas no idioma português. Cito como exemplo as expressões [montanha-russa](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/montanha-russa) e a [roleta-russa](http://www.aulete.com.br/roleta-russa). Estranhamente em inglês usa-se *roller coaster* para montanha russa, o que dá a entender que este uso é próprio do idioma português. Usando um [tradutor automático](https://translate.google.com/), fiquei com a impressão de que outros idiomas latinos usam expressões semelhantes, enquanto que anglo-saxônicos não. Sobre *roleta russa*, parece ser uma expressão de uso geral.

Enfim, gostaria de saber qual a origem do uso de *russo/a* na língua portuguesa? É uma percepção tão somente minha que o uso de *russo* tenha conotação extrema/arriscada ou existem outros usos que contrariem esta lógica?

Comment: Dois exemplos não sempre fazem um padrão. Tem mais?

Comment: @DanGetz não. Mas também não tenho nenhum contrário.

Comment: @DanGetz e gmauch vejam a minha resposta tem um exemplo contrário.

Comment: Por causa da guerra-fria provavelmente os EUA não quiseram adotar a referência.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Essa duas palavras nasceram, não por ser arriscado, mas sim por terem sido criações (ou supostas criações) Russas. Temos também outro exemplo a [**salada-russa**](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/salada-russa) que nada tem a ver com a conotação extrema/arriscada.

#### [salada-russa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salada_russa#Hist.C3.B3ria)

> Foi inventada nos anos 1860 por Lucien Olivier, chef do famoso
> restaurante Hermitage situado na praça Trubnaia, em **Moscovo**. Este
> prato tornou-se muito popular pelos frequentadores do local e a sua
> fama se estendeu.

#### [montanha-russa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montanha-russa#Hist.C3.B3ria)

> As mais antigas montanhas-russas descendem da **Rússia**. Os passeios de trenó no inverno prendiam-se em montes especialmente construídos no gelo, principalmente em torno de São Petersburgo. Foram construídas de 20 a 24 metros de altura e consistiam em uma queda de 50º.

#### [roleta-russa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roleta_russa#Hist.C3.B3ria)

> Existem inúmeras lendas a respeito da invenção da roleta russa. Muitas
> delas, presumivelmente, apontam para a **Rússia**, ou ocorre entre
> soldados russos. Em uma das lendas, prisioneiros russos do Século XIX
> seriam forçados a jogar enquanto os guardas cuidavam das
> consequências. Em outra versão, oficiais desesperados e suicidas do
> exército russo jogavam para impressionarem uns aos outros.